# Is this implicitly calling a copy constructor?

Tags: c++, reference, copy-constructor

I have the following classes:

```
class Player
{
public:
    Inventory& GetInventory()
    {
        return inventory;
    }
private:
    Inventory inventory;
};

class Inventory
{
    // Methods removed for brevity
private:
    std::vector<std::string> items;
};
```

What I'm trying to do is allow a user of the code to modify the contents of `Player::inventory` without being able to reassign it to a different object.  Short example:

```
Player player;

// OK: I want to able to add items.
player.GetInventory().AddItem("Item 1");

// Not OK: I don't want to be able to assign
// Player::inventory to a different Inventory.
Inventory badInventory;
player.GetInventory() = badInventory;
```

I know I can accomplish this by modifying `GetInventory()` to return `Inventory* const`, but this scenario is making me doubt what I believe to be true of references.  I believe they:

1. Are not objects themselves, so do not have an address.
2. Cannot be reassigned during their lifetime.
3. Must be initialised when declared.

That says to me that `badInventory` must somehow be getting copied implicitly.  So I defined a copy constructor, hoping to log the call, like so:

```
Inventory(const Inventory& rhs)
{
    std::cout << "Copy ctor." << std::endl;
}
```

But that never fires.  So my question boils down to: what is happening on this line?

```
player.GetInventory() = badInventory;
```

I'm missing something here, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That line is actually calling the copy assignment operator, not the copy constructor. That's the function declared as

```
Inventory& operator=(const Inventory&);
```

Note that `player.GetInventory()` is an object that *already exists*, so it cannot invoke the copy constructor, simply because you're not constructing anything.

If you want to forbid inventories from being copied, delete these functions:

```
Inventory(const Inventory&) = delete;
Inventory& operator=(const Inventory&) = delete;
```

Or, if your compiler lacks C++11 support, declare them as `private` and don't provide a definition.

```
private:
    Inventory(const Inventory&);
    Inventory& operator=(const Inventory&);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Just to clarify, when you say: `Note that player.GetInventory() is an object that already exists, so it cannot invoke the copy constructor`, that applies only to the copy constructor, and not the copy assignment constructor, is that correct?  Also, does this mean my general usage here to promote encapsulation of `Player`, by using `Inventory* const GetInventory()`, is the way to go, assuming that I just want to prevent reassignment of `Player::inventory` whilst not preventing the copying of `Inventory` itself?

Comment: @John Look up `initialization` versus `assignment`.

Comment: @remyabel I know the difference between them.  I just wasn't aware of the second type of copy constructor, so I'm making sure there wasn't an error in the comment, just to be sure.

Comment: @JohnH Yes, when the copy assignment operator is invoked, it does so on an object that already exists, so you're not actually creating it. The copy constructor is invoked, for example, in a statement like this: `Inventory i2 = i1`, where `i1` is a previously created object. Note that the previous syntax is another way of saying `Inventory i2{i1}`, which might be clearer. Regarding your second question, why don't let the player add things to its inventory instead of grabbing it by yourself?

Comment: @John That doesn't make any sense. Copy construction and copy assignment are not the same thing.

Comment: @remyabel It does if you read my first comment very carefully. Edit: That's exactly why I wanted the clarification, because I _know_ they're not the same thing.

Comment: @John Right, so how could you understand the difference between initialization and assignment if you weren't aware of the copy assignment operator?

Comment: @remyabel I knew the mechanism existed, but I didn't know the actual terminology.

Answer (score 1):

In this scenarion

```
player.GetInventory() = badInventory;
```

there is used the copy assignment operator for class Inventory.

You can define copy/move assignment operators as deleted. For example

```
class Inventory
{
public:
    Inventory & operator =( const Inventory & ) = delete;
    Inventory & operator =( Inventory && ) = delete;
    // Methods removed for brevity
private:
    std::vector<std::string> items;
};
```

Or you can declare them as private member functions.

Though in my opinion it would be better if you would define all required methods of processing the vector as member functions instead of the returning of reference to the vector

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not returning a reference to the vector.  `AddItems`, as well as other functions, are defined as member functions of `Inventory`.  As such, they do not expose the vector as part of the public interface of `Inventory`.